# Image to numpy array to Image and finally again to array resulting in wrong array

Tags: python

I converted an image to numpy array using:

```
arr = np.array(PIL.Image.open('1.jpg'))
```

Then I modified part of the array:

```
arr[0][0][0] = 128
```

and converted the array back to an image:

```
img = PIL.Image.fromarray(np.uint8(arr))
im.save('2.jpg')
```

Then, I converted the 2.jpg image into numpy array and checked value of arr:

```
arr = np.array(PIL.Image.open('2.jpg'))
print(arr)
```

I am getting a completely different array than I got before.
Why is this happening?

Comment: Count it be the `np.uint8(arr)` call?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Nope. Still getting wrong array even after omitting np.uint8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you save the image affects the results.
The jpg compresses the image and alters the values.

About the image formats see here:
 http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html

Use this:

```
arr = np.array(PIL.Image.open('1.jpg')
arr[0][0][0] = 128

img = PIL.Image.fromarray(np.uint8(arr))
im.save('2.bmp')

arr2 = np.array(PIL.Image.open('2.bmp'))
print(arr)
print(arr2)
```

This works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Because `.jpg` is not lossless image format.
If you want to save image as is, save as lossless image format like bmp, tiff, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that your arrays don't match is that you are storing the image as JPEG and this is a lossy format - the two images are visually identical but have been compressed.

If you save your image as a bitmap then load it into an array, they will be identical.